# Error while running batch scripts 'Error message highlight pattern:'

Tags: tfs-2015

I am trying to do a ms, xcopy and other cmd commands in TFS 2015 vNext builds but I am getting the error

```
Error message highlight pattern:
Warning message highlight pattern:
```

Please help

Comment: Those aren't error messages.

Comment: Without the detail error message, we could not help you. Please also [Enable Verbose Debug Mode for TFS Build](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/19/enable-verbose-debug-mode-for-tfs-build-vnext/) by set `system.debug= true` to get more detail log info and share here.

Comment: Any update on this issue, have you figured it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by changing the ***batch task*** tool value from ***cmd.exe*** to ***powershell.exe***. In this case the error was same but the task did the job.